# upgrade to macOS high sierra, bootcamp win10 disk exists but can not prompt when turn on the power

Tags: macos, bootcamp, high-sierra

I just upgrade my mac mini to macOS high sierra.
Before, when I turn on the power, there is the option for me to choose boot from Windows 10 or macOS.
but right now, it boots and enters macOS directly.
I checked and found that BOOTCAMP disk still exist,
all content of the bootcamp hard disk appeared and nothing removed.

Is there any way to activate/import the existed bootcamp disk and add the option for Windows 10/macOS when turn on the power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the option when needed, hold the `alt/opt` key doing boot, it’ll let you choose which OS you want to boot...

Answer (score 1):

The software provided by Apple does not include an option to choose whether to boot Windows 10 or macOS at startup. You must have other third party software installed. If the person who setup your Mac did a good job, you should be able to hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key at startup and determine which icon represents the third party startup manager. Next, you would hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key and select the arrow below the icon. This would fix your problem.

On the other hand, if the person, who setup your Mac, did a lesser job, then the procedure to fix you Mac would proceed as outlined below.

1. Determine what third party software was installed.
2. Figure out where this software is installed.
3. Boot to Recover mode.
4. Open a Terminal application window.
5. Enter the `bless` command with the proper options.